# Continuity and Uniform Continuity of Riemann Zeta function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, riemann-zeta

Let the Riemann Zeta function be expressed as:
$$\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$$
I want to show, it is (1) continuous using that Weierstrass M-test, (2) but not uniformly continuous for $x \geq 1$. My proof goes like the following:

(1) Fix $\delta > 0$ and observe that the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges uniformly for $x \geq \delta + 1$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\delta +1}} < \infty$ and using Weierstrass M-test gives us uniform continuity. Then $\zeta(x)$ is continuous in $[\delta + 1, \infty)$ and we are done.

(2) I want to show that $\zeta(x)$ is unbounded for $x \geq 1$, ...

I am wondering if proof for (1) is correct and the answer for (2).
Thanks!

Comment: The precise asymptotic near $s=1$ is found from $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\sum_{n\ge 1} \int_n^{n+1}(n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}t^{-s}dt)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^t su^{-s-1}dudt$, note this is also the analytic continuation to $s > 0$

Comment: $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\sum_{n\ge 1} (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}t^{-s}dt)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^t su^{-s-1}dudt$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of continuity on $(1,\infty)$ is correct. [ Note that you have written $x \geq 1$ instead of $x>1$.

If the function is uniformly continuous then it would be bounded on $(1,T]$ for any $T \in (0,\infty)$. However $\zeta (x) \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^N  \frac 1 {n^{x}} $ for each $N$. If $M$ is an upper bound for the function choose $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N  \frac 1 n  >M+1$ and then  choose $x$ close enough to $1$ to get a  contradiction.

Comment: I get the intuition, but how can I make it rigorous. How should we simply "choose $x$ close enough to 1" to get that $\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @U.Hill You have a finite sum here and each term is continuous. So $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{x}} \to \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1 n$ as $x \to 1$.